# XFDF URL reference to PDF form not working

Tags: pdf, adobe, fdf, xfdf

I'm populating a PDF form using XFDF. The XFDF is produced by my Java webapp. I want to reference the PDF form from XFDF using a URL because I want form templates to be stored on the server. The form is password-protected, so I can't flatten it server-side with iText.

Using a local path works fine:

```
<f href="C:\Users\...\MyForm.pdf"/>
```

but a URL fails:

```
<f href="http://localhost:8080/app/servlet/PdfForm?id=176"/>
```

From the article below it seems it's possible, but I've looked through the XFDF spec and it doesn't mention URLs, only local paths:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Adobe_XFDF

Neither Acrobat Reader X nor Acrobat Pro X seem to handle it. The browser fires up but and form doesn't get merged. I've tried changing default browser from Chrome to Firefox to IE with no luck.

Does anyone know if a URL reference works?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this by any chance? I am having exactly the same issue and can't seem to solve it...

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I think in the end I abandoned the idea and tried went for an iText approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL should be only http://xx.xxx/xxx/test.pdf, a pdf form, not a stream.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open it in Internet Explorer on a PC with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC installed, but other browsers seem to be unable to do so.
Reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html